# Python - How to use function within another function

Tags: python

I am trying to make variable signatures when sending emails. Depending on the user logged into the OS, this will show a different signature. When trying to do this, i am getting the below error messages.

I have tried 2 options that i am aware of, but to no avail. Please can somebody shed some light on how i can get a function to work within another, or another suggestion to this:

**Example 1:**

```
def signature():
    # User Variable(s)
    user = os.getlogin()
    name1 = "example1"
    name2 = "example2"
    name3 = "example3"

    # Signature Variable(s)
    if user == name1:
        print("Kind Regards\n"
              "Example 1\n"
              "Job Role")
    elif user == name2:
        print("Kind Regards\n"
              "Example 2\n"
              "Job Role")
    elif user == name3:
        print("Kind Regards\n"
              "Example 3\n"
              "Job Role")
    else:
        print("Kind Regards\n"
              "Other\n"
              "Job Role")

def mail_send():
    outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = "example@outlook.co.uk"
    mail.Subject = "Python Test Mail"
    mail.Body = "Hi," \
                "\n\nPlease ignore this email." \
                "\n\nThis is an original message." \
                "\n" + (str(signature)) \
```

**Output from mail which was sent:**

Hi,

Please ignore this email.

This is an original message.

<function signature at 0x000002B9F726A160>

**Example 2:**

```
def signature():
    # User Variable(s)
    user = os.getlogin()
    name1 = "example1"
    name2 = "example2"
    name3 = "example3"

    # Signature Variable(s)
    if user == name1:
        print("Kind Regards\n"
              "Example 1\n"
              "Job Role")
    elif user == name2:
        print("Kind Regards\n"
              "Example 2\n"
              "Job Role")
    elif user == name3:
        print("Kind Regards\n"
              "Example 3\n"
              "Job Role")
    else:
        print("Kind Regards\n"
              "Other\n"
              "Job Role")

def mail_send():
    outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = "example@outlook.co.uk"
    mail.Subject = "Python Test Mail"
    mail.Body = "Hi," \
                "\n\nPlease ignore this email." \
                "\n\nThis is an original message." \
                "\n" + (str(signature())) \
```

**Output 2 from mail which was sent:**

Hi,

Please ignore this email.

This is an original message.

None

Comment: You're almost there: in the function signature, replace `print` by `return`. Then use your 2nd code (the one where you *call* the function with parentheses `signature()`

Comment: You can also replace `str(signature())` with just `signature()` since you are returning a string. Also for the record, fstrings are quite useful. You could have something like `f'This is a test message.\n{signature()}'`

Answer (score 1):

- Need to `return` from function to make the variable created available to the calling function
- function call is `myfunc()` not `myfunc`

eg:

```
def signature():
  # User Variable(s)
  user = os.getlogin()
  name1 = "example1"
  name2 = "example2"
  name3 = "example3"

  # Signature Variable(s)
  if user == name1:
      sig_str = "Kind Regards\n"+
          "Example 1\n"+
          "Job Role"
  elif user == name2:
      sig_str = "Kind Regards\n"+
            "Example 2\n"+
            "Job Role"
  elif user == name3:
      sig_str = "Kind Regards\n"+
            "Example 3\n"+
            "Job Role"
  else:
      sig_str = "Kind Regards\n"+
            "Other\n"+
            "Job Role"
  return sig_str

def mail_send():
  outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")
  mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
  mail.To = "example@outlook.co.uk"
  mail.Subject = "Python Test Mail"
  mail.Body = "Hi," \
            "\n\nPlease ignore this email." \
            "\n\nThis is an original message." \
            "\n" + signature() \
```